# How can I get my table view to redisplay data when objects are deleted?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I have table view which is in a view controller that inherits from UITableViewController.

I use a NSFetchedResultsController that I use to fetch the table data from my core data store. I've tried it with both caching on and off.

I set the delegate of the NSFetchedResultsController to be self and I've implemented controllerDidChangeContent in my view controller.

I've always implemented the table view delegate functions including commitEditingStyle which is called when the user deletes a row.

Here is what happens. The user swipes and deletes a row and commitEditingStyle is called as expected. In that function, I modify my core data objects to so that they are effectively deleted from results. In other words, if you ran the query I passed NSFetchedResultsController again, that row would now no longer be in the results set.

This alone is not enough, so I added a called to tableView reloadData at the end of commitEditingStyle. Still no luck, so I added a refresh button that calls reloadData and that doesn't help either. Going to another view controller (by hitting "back") and returning to the page doesn't usually work, but eventually it figures it out and the row will disappear correctly. Rerunning the program from scratch always works, of course, but how can I get my tableView to update correctly? controllerDidChangeContent never gets called by the way. I thought reloadData would be enough, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Might wanna up that accept rating if you wanna get help

Comment: ok, i boosted it up, where are my answers :)

Comment: On a hunch, maybe you need to tell the MOC to save?

Comment: good suggestion, but I've tried both processingPending changes and saving.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the Fetched results controller's controller didChangeObject: delegate method?

The easiest way is  to create a new project using navigation based template with core-data on and compare the RootViewController with your code. RootViewController already contains the code to perform the update after tableview modification.

It is something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the managed object for the given index path
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

}

Then use this method to update the table view

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```